# Using .replace to check regex for space, comma and period?

Tags: jquery, regex

My attempt here is not working:

```
var n = $('.class').val().replace(/ /g,'',/,/g,'.').length;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/[ ,.]/g
```

`[]` defines a character group, that matches one of the characters inside.

---

A minor optimisation would be to add repetition quantifier (`+`).

```
/[ ,.]+/g
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check for a comma `,`, space `\s` or period `.`, you could use the following Regular Expression :

```
/[,.\s]/g
```

The slashes are simply escape characters as a period is commonly used to denote any character and `\s` will match any instances of white-space.

So if you wanted to replace all of these, just use :

```
var output = input.replace(/[,.\s]/g,'replacement-string');
```

Comment: Actually a dot inside a character group has no special meaning.

Comment: Thanks ndn. I suppose it's just an old habit. I'll strip them off accordingly.